# How add a CSS class on form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have a simple form with some inputs marked with `required`, how do I add the class `invalid` or `valid` in the specific input that is valid or invalid?

Only 1 input receives the `invalid` class.

```js
const $input = document.querySelector("input")
const $form = document.querySelector("#form")
const $button = document.querySelector("#button")


$button.addEventListener('click', () => validate())

const validate = () => {
  if (!$form.checkValidity()) {
    console.log('invalid')
    $input.classList.add('invalid')
  } else {
    console.log('valid')
    $input.classList.add('valid')
  }
}
```

```css
input.invalid {
  background: red;
}

input.valid {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="nome" required>
  <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Number" name="number">
  <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Size" name="size" required>
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="blue">
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="red">
</form>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: First, I think you need to use `document.querySelectorAll` for your input...

Comment: After that, instead of checking the form's validity using the built-in function, you may need to loop through all the inputs and check for two things: (1) if the input is required, and (2) if the input has any content. If it IS required and DOESN't have any content, add the `invalid` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll

```js
const $input = document.querySelectorAll("input")
const $form = document.querySelector("#form")
const $button = document.querySelector("#button")


$button.addEventListener('click', () => validate())

const validate = () => {
  if (!$form.checkValidity()) {
    console.log('invalid')
    $input.forEach(input => input.classList.add('invalid'));
  } else {
    console.log('valid')
    $input.forEach(input => input.classList.add('valid''));
  }
}
```

```css
input.invalid {
  background: red;
}

input.valid {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="nome" required>
  <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Number" name="number">
  <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Size" name="size" required>
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="blue">
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="red">
</form>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```